# Write 3 arrays to 1

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have 3 arrays: x, y and z. How can I write all three to one in one-after-one mode?
For example: I have X=1,2 Y=3,4 Z=5,6
I need an array W = X[1],Y[1],Z[1],X[2],Y[2],Z[2] ... X[n],Y[n],Z[n]

```
        float[] posX = new float[rmv2.lod[0].VerticesCount[0]];
        float[] posY = new float[rmv2.lod[0].VerticesCount[0]];
        float[] posZ = new float[rmv2.lod[0].VerticesCount[0]];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i += 3)
        {
                posX[i] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].X;
                posY[i + 1] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Y;
                posZ[i + 2] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Z;
        }
```

Comment: You could use an object of type `List<float>`.

Comment: Why are you using arrays anyway?  List<T> would be so much easier.  Then if you really need an array at the end, you could call `ToArray()` on the list.

Comment: Maybe hes going for high performance...

Comment: @Dr.Fre -- Having to re-dimension an array over and over again does not result in high performance.  For instance, if his input arrays have more than two elements -- i.e. you don't want to hard-code 2 elements -- you have to find the number of elements in each input array and continue to redim the output array accordingly.

Comment: "rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[j]" is a list already but it contains additional data such as bones, weights, uvs and such. I need to split my position X, Y and Z arrays from rest info, put them all into one array and export to dae(xml) as a float array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the w array you're trying to write the output to. Are you looking for something like this?

```
    int n = rmv2.lod[0].VerticesCount[0];

    float[] posX = new float[n];
    float[] posY = new float[n];
    float[] posZ = new float[n];
    float[] w = new float[n * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        posX[i] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].X;
        posY[i] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Y;
        posZ[i] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Z;
        w[i * 3 + 0] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].X;
        w[i * 3 + 1] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Y;
        w[i * 3 + 2] = rmv2.lod[0].Mesh[0].Vertex[i].Z;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at jagged arrays...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float[] x = new float[] { 1, 2, 9 };
float[] y = new float[] { 3, 4 };
float[] z = new float[] { 5, 6 };

int max = Math.Max(x.Length, Math.Max(y.Length, z.Length));
List<float> combined = new List<float>();

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    if (x.Length > i) combined.Add(x[i]);
    if (y.Length > i) combined.Add(y[i]);
    if (z.Length > i) combined.Add(z[i]);
}
```

Produces a list with the combined arrays, regardless of their original lengths.

> 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 9

Comment: Very cool idea but unfortunately it records all zeros. Probably coz LINQ xml writes values only from arrays

Comment: @MrJox If you want to make an array from the list, use the `List<T>.ToArray` Method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you, try this solution. With this method arrays can have different length

```
static T[] ConcatOneAfterOne<T>(params T[][] arrays)
{
    int outputArrayLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
    {
        outputArrayLength += arrays[i].Length;
    }

    T[] output = new T[outputArrayLength];

    int outputIndex = 0;
    int sourceIndex = 0;

    while (outputIndex != outputArrayLength)
    {
        for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arrays.Length; arrayIndex++)
        {
            if (sourceIndex < arrays[arrayIndex].Length)
            {
                output[outputIndex++] = arrays[arrayIndex][sourceIndex];
            }
        }

        sourceIndex++;
    }

    return output;
}

[Test]
static void ConcatOneAfterOneTest()
{
    int[] result = ConcatOneAfterOne(new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 }, new[] { 5, 6 });
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 }, result);
}
```